# "mvn install " A maven commend not installed a jar from local into maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, jar

I am new to MAC. I need to install some jars from local to maven repository.

Steps I followed :-

1. Kept jars "monte-screen-recorder.jar" at my local  and run the below command to install into Maven repository.

> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile="\Downloads\monte-screen-recorder.jar" -DgroupId="org.monte" -DartifactId="monte-screen-recorder" -Dversion=0.7.7 -Dpackaging="jar"
> ```

SUCCESS message is shown in terminal. But actual jar is not present in Maven repository.

```
INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/admnistrator/Documents/workSpaceIOS/test-automation-library/imageClient.jar to /Users/admnistrator/.m2/repository/com/experitest/client/imageClient/1.0/imageClient-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.527s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 17 17:02:07 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please let me know where I am making a mistake .

Comment: I thought install wrote JARs to your local repo and deploy uploaded them to remote repos.

Comment: Read the documentation: "Installs a file in the local repository."

Answer (score 0):

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/admnistrator/Documents/workSpaceIOS/test-automation-library/imageClient.jar to /Users/admnistrator/.m2/repository/com/experitest/client/imageClient/1.0/imageClient-1.0.jar
```

Maven install the image client jar file in your local maven repo curently. So you must have write a wrong command.
Can you show the full log (command + maven in the same log) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this central repository instead:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pojosontheweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>monte-repack</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```